# Preview virtual spaces in menu bar (like ubuntu)

Tags: menu-bar, spaces, mission-control

Is it possible to have a preview of the virtual spaces in the menu bar, like this https://github.com/maho2nd/enhanced-ubuntu-workspace-indicator?

[image: ss of ubuntu ex]

More generally, I'd like to know which spaces are clear and which are occupied.

**NOTE:** I'm already using [WhichSpaces](https://github.com/gechr/WhichSpace) but it only gives the current space as an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling I was able to find this commercial app that looks like it does what you want. It's called [TotalSpaces2](https://totalspaces.binaryage.com/) and looks to cost ~$12 US.

There a [overview video](https://player.vimeo.com/video/161810791) that highlights all of its features. You can see an overview of all the apps on your various spaces as shown below:

[image: ss#1]

From the look of the docs & features I think what you're looking for is the Overview Grid. That's shown above in a larger spread of spaces and below with a smaller spread.

[image: ss#2]

Comment: You may want to check Total Saces.  i think you have to turn SIP off to use it.  Not sure about that but i would check first.  If turning it off is ok with you then i wouldn't worry bout it. Total Spaces is very nice.